# XSLT Pass parameter

Tags: xml, xslt, parameters

I've been looking at other questions but I can't quite see what I'm doing wrong.
I want to pass a parameter to select certain results only, but I'm having problems with the parameter.

The html (disregard the IE part)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("f.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("xsl.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

  xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "testParam", "voo");
  // alert(xsltProcessor.getParameter(null,"voc"));

  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = "";

  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }


}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
    <li><u><a onclick="displayResult();" style="cursor: pointer;">test1</a></u></li>
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="vocaroos.xsl"?>
<test>
    <artist name="Bert">
        <voo>bert1</voo>
    </artist>
    <artist name="Pet">
        <voo>pet1</voo>
    </artist>
</test>
```

xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="testParam"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body >
  <h2>Titleee</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Teeeeeest</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="test/artist">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="$testParam"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the outcome (left)

[image: outcome]

On the left is what this does and on the right, what I actually want. I was expecting that

```
<xsl:value-of select="$testParam"/>
```

would do the same as

```
<xsl:value-of select="voo"/>     (right outcome)
```

since I do setParameter(null, "testParam", "voo"); in the html, but for some reason the xsl doesn't use "voo" as select, but instead writes "voo".

I've been trying different things but nothing works. Where's the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the parameter is the string "voo", which is why xsl:value-of applied to the parameter returns the string "voo". There is no reason to expect the XSLT processor to treat "voo" as an XPath expression to be evaluated.

If the value of the parameter is an element name and you want to select elements with that name, you can do something like select="*[name()=$testParam]". If it's a more general XPath expression then you will need an xx:evaluate() extension.

Comment: Thanks, select="*[name()=$testParam]" does exactly what I need. I thought that writing select="voo" would just pass a string too, in this case "voo", and XSLT would then take that string and use it as XPath expression to evaluate. This is why I thought that I could simply give select a parameter with a string. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT does not do dynamic evaluation in either 1.0 or 2.0. Certain extension functions such as [`saxon:evaluate`](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensions/functions/evaluate.xml) would allow for this but their availability is dependent on which XSLT engine you are using. The XSLT 3.0 recommendation adds this natively with [`xsl:evaluate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate) but there are very few XSLT engines which have implemented 3.0 support yet (saxon being one of them).

Comment: Thanks, should I run into further complications, I might just not use XSLT, since I really just wanted to quickly display some data, in a certain format, for testing purposes.